# ¿Cómo insertar los registros desde una tabla creada "manualmente" con jquery?

Tags: jquery, mvc, asp.net-core

Gracias por leer.
Logré crear una tabla con Jquery de acuerdo a valores que el usuario ingresa. Necesitaría ahora insertar esos datos a la base de datos. Es una simple tabla donde quiero ingresar un plan de pagos que el cliente acepte.

**Código tabla**

```
$("#botonplan").click(function () {
        var filas = $("#cuotas").val();
        var monto = $("#monto").val();
        var tabla = "";
        var result = $("#tabla");
        tabla += "<table>";
        tabla += "<thead>";
        tabla += "<tr>";
        tabla += "<th>Cuota</th>";
        tabla += "<th>Monto</th>";
        tabla += "</tr>";
        tabla += "</thead>";
        tabla += "<tbody>";
        for (var i = 0; i < filas; i++) {
            tabla += "<tr>";
            tabla += "<td>" + (i + 1) + "</td>";
            tabla += "<td>" + monto + "</td > ";
            tabla += "</tr>";
        }
        tabla += "</tbody>";
        tabla += "</table>";
        result.html(tabla);
    });
```

**View**

```
 <div class="row">
    <select id="cuotas" class="form-control input-sm" style="width:120px">
        <option value="0">--Seleccione Cuotas--</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
        <option value="8">8</option>
        <option value="9">9</option>
        <option value="10">10</option>
        <option value="11">11</option>
        <option value="12">12</option>
    </select>
    <br />
    <input id="monto" placeholder="Monto Cuotas" class="form-control input-sm" style="width:120px" />
    <br />
    <div>
        <button id="botonplan" class="btn btn-info btn-sm">Crear</button>
    </div>
</div>

<table id="tabla" class="table table-hover">

</table>
```

En el controlador no tengo nada escrito porque la verdad es que no se como hacerlo.
La duda me surge, ya que si bien se crea la tabla, no hay nada "escrito" en la página (cuando aprieto crtl+u en el explorador -perdón pero no se como explicarlo-).

Desde ya muchas gracias.
Saludos.

Comment: Puedes revisar este enlace: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/165410/ASP-NET-MVC-Editable-DataTable-jQuery-DataTables-a

Comment: Gracias, ahora lo leere!